# call of template member function

Tags: c++, templates

If I have a class

```
class A {

  template<class T>
  void foo(T t);

};
```

what is the difference / the way of the book to call `foo`?

```
a.foo(t)
```

or

```
a.foo<X>(t)
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a.foo(t)` will basically deduce `T` to the type of `t`. If this is fine with you, use this.

`a.foo<X>` will force `T` to be `X` and the correctness of the expression now depends on if `t` is convertible to `X`. Sometimes you desire this, if you want `t` to be converted to `X`, but you could always write this as `a.foo(X{t})`. The second form is not entirely equivalent, since it also allows explicit conversions.

Answer (score 2):

In the second variant, `X` may not be the type of `t`. E.g., if `t` is a `float`, but you say `a.foo<int>(t)`, no floating variant will be deduced, but rather the integer-variant (if not exists already), and a `float`-to-`int` conversion will happen.

If the types are identical, there is no difference. However, one never knows for the whole lifetime of the code whether the types never change.